# Let compiler select multiplication algorithm depending on architecture

Tags: c++

[Chapter 6.3 "Know an Algorithm's Complexity" of the book Real-Time C++](https://books.google.de/books?id=xTNEAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PA101#v=onepage&q&f=false) contains the following listing:

```
std::uint16_t a = UINT16_C(55555);
std::uint16_t b = UINT16_C(61234);

void do_something()
{
    // Unsigned 16 x 16 --> 32-bit = 3,401,854,870.

    std::uint32_t result = a * static_cast<std::uint32_t>(b);
}
```

In the text, the author states that it is better to cast only one operand of the multiplication to `std::uint32_t`, because then the compiler may "choose between the better of 16 x 16 --> 32-bit multiplication and 32 x 32 --> 32-bit multiplication and still get the right answer" depending on the CPU architecture (e.g., 8-bit or 32-bit).

I do not understand how the compiler is allowed to perform a 16 x 16 --> 32-bit multiplication, since operand `b` is explicitly cast to `std::uint32_t`. If I understood the integer promotion / conversion rules correctly, operand `a` will be promoted to `std::uint32_t` before the multiplication and the compiler can only perform a 32 x 32 --> 32-bit multiplication.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The quote seems dubious to me; the author is imagining a world where a compiler can infer 16x16 from 16x32, but not from 32x32.

Comment: Your thoughts/analysis sound correct to me. Unfortunately it looks like no [errata sheet](https://github.com/ckormanyos/real-time-cpp/issues/11) exists, despite some known issues (I do not know if this is one of those known issues or not).

Comment: Compiler may knows (fro the type of cast) that higher bits are zero, so may do some optimizations.

Comment: When working with small microcontrollers there are large variations in execution speed. You really have to look at the generated assy code and cpu specs to fine tune problems such as this. The results aren't very portable and different techniques would likely work better with different processors. That's the nature of low end embedded systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ standard specifies only *observable behavior* of a program [intro.execution:1]:

> Rather, conforming implementations are required to emulate (only) the observable behavior of the abstract machine as explained below.

Since you don't *observe* the result of `static_cast<std::uint32_t>(b)`, a standard-compliant compiler is not obliged to actually compute this sub-expression. It is only required to perform multiplication *as if* one of the operands being 32-bit (and thus the result not being 16-bit, which is the only observable implication here).

Comment: But that doesn't make casting *one* parameter (rather than *both*) any more optimal. The exact same logic could be applied if *both* parameters had been cast to a `std::uint32_t`.

Comment: I just answered OP's question about why isn't a compiler constrained to 32x32-bit multiplication. Your question should be addressed to the book author---he states that casting both operands would result in 32x32-bit multiplication, but gives no explanation.